# How to Override Intermediate tmp Tables Creation in DBT-GLUE

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena, dbt, apache-iceberg

I'm encountering an issue with the DBT-GLUE adapter while working on an Iceberg table in my project. The temporary (tmp) table generated by DBT contains null values, which are carried over to the final Iceberg table, causing alignment issues. Below are the details of my setup:

1. DBT Version: 1.7.4
2. DBT-GLUE Adapter Version: 1.7.1

I've configured my DBT profiles with the following Spark configurations:

```
conf: |
  spark.sql.legacy.allowNonEmptyLocationInCTAS=true
  spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions
  spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
  spark.sql.warehouse=
  spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog
  spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.catalog-impl=org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog
  spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.io-impl=org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO
  spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.lock-impl=org.apache.iceberg.aws.dynamodb.DynamoDbLockManager
  spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.lock.table=myGlueLockTable
  spark.sql.legacy.createTableColumnTypesInCatalog=true
  spark.sql.sources.default=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog
  spark.sql.sources.write.semantic=ORC
```

The issue is isolated to the creation of the tmp table with the following SQL statement:

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE test_table LOCATION 's3://BucketName/Iceberg_db/tmp_test_table' AS SELECT * FROM tmp_tmp_test_table")
```

Upon inspecting the table in Athena, I observed incorrect values for input format, output format, and serde serialization lib:

```
Input Format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
Output Format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
Serde Serialization Lib: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
```

When I recreate the process in an interactive notebook and use the following SQL statement:

```
spark.sql("""
CREATE TABLE tmp_test_table
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/iceberg_db/tmp_test_table'
AS SELECT * FROM tmp_tmp_test_table
""")
```

The correct values are enforced:

```
Input Format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat
Output Format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat
Serde Serialization Lib: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe
```

This resolves the null issue. My question is, what are the ways to enforce the correct input, output formats, and serde serialization library? While creating GLUE jobs and skipping DBT seems valid, I'd like to set up this project to allow SQL-focused analytics teams to onboard and contribute using the DBT adapter. Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated.